# How to setup Firebase Offline Authentication with Nuxt SSR

Tags: firebase, authentication, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to build a Nuxt SSR application using `@nuxtjs/firebase` and `@nuxtjs/pwa`
My authentication works as expected when online but when when the user is offline I get this error in console

```
asyncToGenerator.js:8 Uncaught (in promise) t {code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.", a: null}
```

Here's the screenshot of the error message:

[image: Nuxt Firebase Offline Error Message Screenshot]

This error freezes my app (my navigation hamburger menu doesn't respond)

PWA config in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en',
      background_color: '#000000',
    },
    meta: {
      nativeUI: true,
      appleStatusBarStyle: 'black',
      theme_color: '#000000',
    },
    config: {
      enabled: true
    },
    workbox: {
      importScripts: [
        '/firebase-auth-sw.js'
      ],
      dev: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    }
  }
```

Here is my Firebase config in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
firebase: {
    config: {
      apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
      authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
      databaseURL: process.env.databaseURL,
      projectId: process.env.projectId,
      storageBucket: process.env.storageBucket,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.messagingSenderId,
      appId: process.env.appId,
      measurementId: process.env.measurementId
    },
    
    services: {
      auth: {
        ssr: true,
        initialize: {
          // use authData from action in custom mutation
          // onAuthStateChangedMutation: 'ON_AUTH_STATE_CHANGED_MUTATION',
          onAuthStateChangedAction: 'onAuthStateChangedAction'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My `onAuthStateChangedAction` in `store/index.js`:

```js
async onAuthStateChangedAction({ dispatch, commit }, { authUser }) {
    if(!authUser) return commit(MUTATION_TYPE.REMOVE_USER)

    // if user is already authenticated
    // get authenticated user profile from firestore
    dispatch('getUser', authUser)
    if(process.browser) commit(MUTATION_TYPE.SET_TOKEN, localStorage.token)
  }
```

Comment: did you manage to get this working? I am trying to do the same but unsuccessful so far

Comment: @JoeEarly unfortunately I couldn't but ditched `@nuxtjs/firebase` and wrote my own firebase configuration so that I check if the user is online first, if not then I don't try to authenticate. It sort of works since it does not throw any errors and blocks my app.

Comment: I think this is what I will have to do, I also ditched the firebase module but still getting them same error.